# What will happen to the center of mass of the human body when a person carries a weight with one hand?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, collision

What will happen to the center of mass of the human body when a person carries a weight with one hand a briefcase for example.

Wouldn't the center of mass move horizontally towards the side carrying the weight?

Comment: It does indeed. For this reason, we tend to lean in the opposite direction (palpable with heavy objects) and adjust our gait to try to move the COM back to a central position.

Comment: What is unclear is _why_ you are asking. There has to be more to this than just the question in the title alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would of course. And so the resultant weight (your's + the weight of what you are carrying) starts acting through this new and **horizontally shifted** (***maybe* vertically shifted too**) Center of Mass.

Notice that all this while your weight was being balanced by the normal reaction from the surface on which you were standing. Also, as only 2 forces were acting along the vertical direction, they were surely acting along the same vertical line (joining the center of mass and the contact point between you and the surface) and hence had no resulting torque about any point.

[image: Force and torque balanced ~ Equilibrium]

Now, however the center of mass has been horizontally displaced and is no more "vertically above" this point of contact with the ground where the normal force acts. Hence though increased normal reaction balances out the forces, there is a net torque so you might risk falling or toppling over.

[image: Force balanced but unbalanced torque ~ Toppling]

This is counteracted by bending in the other direction so as to bring back the center of mass to a position vertically above the contact point.

Another interesting point to note is that if you manage to carry another load on the opposite side, now the center of mass doesn't move and hence you don't topple.

The general idea is that the center of mass of the system is the center of mass of the 2 supposedly point masses present at the center of masses of the individual components of the system. So, the new center of mass after putting on 1 weight is, naturally, shifted towards this weight. Morover this shift depend on the weight of the load you carry.

The block shown is just for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

With briefcase included you have a two body problem. The man has his own CM the briefcase its own. The CM of the system (Man + briefcase) will lie along the line joining the CM of the two.